# How to plot real roots of complex polynomials avoiding branch cuts?

Tags: plotting, matrix, linear-algebra

Lets say I have the following matrix:

```
M={{1,3+E^(I x),-1+2I x},{3+E^(-I x),2,E^(3I x)},{-1-2I x,E^(-3I x),-2}};
```

$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 3+\mathrm e^{ix} & -1+2ix\\3+\mathrm e^{-ix}&2&\mathrm e^{3ix}\\-1-2ix&\mathrm e^{-3ix}&-2\end{pmatrix}
$$

The matrix, being Hermitian, has real eigenvalues. If I plot them, I get the following graph:

```
Eigenvalues[M]
Plot[%, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

As you can see, we get discontinuous curves at $x\approx 0.51$, I believe, because of the branch cuts of the roots of the characteristic polynomial (ie, the roots are something like $A(x)\pm B(x)$ and the sign depends on $x$, so the roots change $A(x)+B(x)\to A(x)-B(x)$ at some $x\approx 0.51$). My question is: how can I solve this issue?

Please, consider the following aspects in regard to possible answers:

1) The curves need not be drawn in different colors: they can all be, for example blue.

2) The actual matrix I have is much more complicated that $M$, and it depends on a lot of parameters, so a definite localisation of the discontinuities has to be found at the time of plotting (no *exact algebra* is possible).

**My attepmt**

Draw the curves at specific points:

```
Eigenvalues[M]
ListPlot[Transpose@Table[%, {x, -1, 1, .05}],PlotStyle->Gray]
```

[image: image2]

This is not really convincing, because Id rather have a continuous curve, as with Plot. `Joined->True` doesnt help. There has to be a better way.

**ADDENDUM**

As @J.M. said, this can be fixed by defining a function:

```
m[x_]:=Eigenvalues[M]
```

The problem is, this doesnt work for more complex situations; consider, for example, an extension of the matrix above:

```
M2={{1,3+E^(I x),-1+2I x,E^(I x)},{3+E^(-I x),2,Exp[3I x],1},{-1-2I x, E^(-3I x),-2,3},{E^(-I x),1,3,4}};
```

$$
M_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1+3\mathrm e^{ix} & -1+2ix & \mathrm e^{ix}\\
3+\mathrm e^{-ix} &2&\mathrm e^{3ix}&1\\
-1-2ix & \mathrm e^{-3ix}&-2&3\\
\mathrm e^{-ix}&1&3&4\end{pmatrix}
$$

so that

```
m2[x_]:=Eigenvalues[M2]
Plot[m2[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: image3]

the same behaviour as before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
Plot[Sort@m2[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This does it for all the matrices I tried. Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

I'm kicking myself for not thinking of [ybeltukov's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100651/4346) answer, but here's mine. It's another (less efficient) way of sorting, but this has the advantage of preserving colorings.

```
pts = Table[m2[x], {x, -1., 1, 1/32.}];

Do[
  pts[[i]] = MinimalBy[
    Permutations[pts[[i]]], 
    Norm[Abs[pts[[i - 1]] - #]] &
  ][[1]], 
  {i, 2, Length[pts]}
];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[pts], DataRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this works on more complex situations, but if you just define it as a function, it appears to give what you are looking for:

```
m[x_] := Eigenvalues[M]
Plot[m[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added to the post a different matrix, where defining a function does not fix the problem.