# Getting rid of discontinuities in plots caused by square roots, logarithms, `Arg`, etc

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning

I encounter this very often, here is just one recent example: I want

```
StreamPlot[ReIm[Sqrt[x+I y]],{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},StreamStyle->"Line"]
```

and because of square root ambiguity get this unpleasant slit on the left:

[image]

Doing this with arrows reveals the reason -

[image]

Having seen this I managed to figure out how to fill the gap,

```
StreamPlot[{Sign[y]Sqrt[(Sqrt[x^2+y^2]+x)/2],Sqrt[(Sqrt[x^2+y^2]-x)/2]},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]
```

gives what I want, namely

[image]

However this is clearly ad hoc and clumsy, and also there are more complicated cases where I don't know how to proceed, like e. g. those ugly white crosses in

```
ContourPlot[Arg[JacobiCN[x+I y,1/2]],{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},ColorFunction->Hue]
```

[image]

Is there some uniform remedy for such cases?

Comment: It doesn't really fix your problem, but it looks better `ContourPlot[Arg[JacobiCN[x + I y, 1/2]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, ExclusionsStyle -> Red]`

Comment: I think Riemann was the first to study this problem seriously. See, for instance, [(1000973)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100973/plotting-riemann-surface-of-wz-sqrt1-z2). It's not real clear to me how general an answer you want. On the one hand, you seek to remove the discontinuities of discontinuous functions, which seems impossible in general. It is possible in the two examples because of a certain coincidence or symmetry between the discontinuity and the image desired.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree that the question is not well enough formulated. Indeed I had in mind so to say "removable" discontinuities - i. e. when what I want to plot is actually continuous. It is slightly tricky in the first example: discontinuity is actually *not* removable there, but one can drag the line of discontinuity around, and what I did was to move it from the negative to the positive horizontal half-axis: in this way it is not visible in the plot since the flow lines are parallel to it near it.

Comment: I don't ever remember that there was a general method to patch through discontinuities. There was always an element of art involved...

Comment: related: [How to plot real roots of complex polynomials avoiding branch cuts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100647/34893).

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. At least for the square root, the following must be possible: if ambiguity is only in the direction (like with the square root), I would like to plot curves tangent to a given field of (directionless) line elements (i. e. a differential form). As for `Arg`, I believe `ColorFunction -> Hue` should be able to remove any ambiguity involved, no?

Comment: If you're just using `Hue[]` to visualize phase, then yes, `Hue[]` along with `Exclusions -> None` ought to do it.