# Ugly streaks caused by Arg in a contour plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, complex, discontinuity

I had a more general question about a similar problem more than two years ago, [Getting rid of discontinuities in plots caused by square roots, logarithms, `Arg`, etc](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182872/35000), which got lots of interesting feedback but no definite answer.

So I decided to focus on something more obviously urgent and simple.

Here is the result of

```
ContourPlot[Log[Abs[Sinh[Sinh[x+I y]]]],{x,-4,4},{y,-4,4},
 MeshFunctions->{Arg[Sinh[Sinh[#1+I #2]]]&},
 Mesh->11,PlotPoints->150,Contours->50]
```

[image]

I guess I don't even need to ask: I want to get rid of those rough thick black lines, that's all.

PS Heard rumours that it might be incorporated in version 12. I have 11.0.1.0, but still, let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Generally, `MeshFunctions` should be continuous. Discontinuities lead to such ugly streaks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the discontinuity in `Arg`.  One way to correct it is to apply a continuous periodic function (of period $2\pi$) to it.  I used `TriangleWave` so that the differences between mesh lines would remain the same.

```
ContourPlot[Log[Abs[Sinh[Sinh[x + I y]]]],
 {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
 MeshFunctions -> {TriangleWave[
     Arg[Sinh[Sinh[#1 + I #2]]]/(2 Pi) - 1/24] &}, 
 Mesh -> {1/6 + Range[-3, 2]/3},
 PlotPoints -> 201, Contours -> 50]
```

[image]

***Alternative***

This takes a bit longer for a high-quality plot, but it shows the `Arg[]` nicely.  A bit hard to figure out how to scale the `ColorFunction`, too.

```
ComplexPlot[Sinh[Sinh[z]], {z, -4 - 4 I, 4 + 4 I},
 PlotPoints -> 801, Mesh -> {51, 1/6 + Range[-3, 2]/3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Log@Abs[#2] &, 
   TriangleWave[Arg[#2]/(2 Pi) - 1/24] &},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, GrayLevel[0.]],
 ColorFunction -> {(Evaluate@
      ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"][
       0.5 + Clip[Log[#7] - 6, {-15, 15}]/30] &), "CyclicArg"}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, RasterSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: Very clean solution, thanks! One correction though: I think you mean a *continuous* periodic function, since `Arg` itself is in fact periodic.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Right, it should be continuous.